# Facebook login on Android always returns isCancelled = true when asking for email (second time)

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, react-native-fbsdk

I am writing an app in React Native and I have trouble with Facebook login on Android device. My code looks like this:

```
 LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile,email'])
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.isCancelled) {
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {...})
      }
   })
```

When I ask for permissions: public_profile -> everything works. But when I add email permission, than only when my app is first installed, loginWithPermissions returns `isCancelled = false`. And every other time I get response `isCancelled = true;`.

So this code will work just one time and every other time, `isCancelled` will be true.

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I accidentally wrote permissions as one item of an array separated by coma: `['public_profile,email']`.
It should be two separated items of an array `['public_profile', 'email']`.